# success в js не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, php, html

Не срабатывает успех в js.
Есть обработчик, есть файл где выпадающий список. Выбрав пункт в списке, отсылается в js и отправляется в обработчик (все успешно меняется), но из обработчика я посылаю еще значение обратно, оно не приходит.
js:

```js
<script>
function tstsel(opt){
    
        var group = opt.value;
        
        $.ajax({
        url: "../../system/user/js/permissions.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ({ member_id: <?php echo $member_id; ?>, member_group: group }),
        success: function(data){
            
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            
            if(obj.status_done == '1'){
                toastr.success('Группа выставлена');
            
            }   
        }
        
    });
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

```html
<select class="select2 form-control form-control-lg" onchange="tstsel(this);">
                                    <option value="<?php echo $member_group; ?>" selected><?php echo $name_group_member; ?></option>
                                    <option value="1">Исполнитель</option>
                                    <option value="2">Заказчик</option>
                                    <option value="4">Модератор</option>
                                    <option value="5">Администратор</option>
                                    </select>
```

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    
$member_id=$_POST['member_id'];
$member_group=$_POST['member_group'];
    
include("../../../config/bd.php");

$res = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `user_group`='$member_group' WHERE `user_id`='$member_id'");
$data = array(
  'status_done' => '1'
);

$json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data: ({ member_id: '<?php echo $member_id; ?>', member_group: group }),

...

  var obj = data;
```

1. Если переменная `$member_id` не является числом (а, к примеру, строкой) ее значение в JavaScript-е надо заключить в кавычки. Без кавычек получится код, обращающийся к необъявленной переменной, что вызывет ошибку выполнения, или вообще синтаксически неверный код, что вызовет ошибку парсера.
2. Вы используете `dataType: 'json',` в `$.ajax` и возвращаете JSON. В таком случае `data` уже объект, полученный из этого JSON-а.

Comment: Моя благодарность. Странно просто, в другой моей наработке все нормально)

Comment: @TopGate Я сейчас занят, но позже напишу, в чем тут дело. Вам было бы полезно разобраться, почему эти исправления помогли.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное!